# How do I run a function before each test when using qUnit?

Tags: javascript, tdd, nunit, qunit

What is the equivalent of nUnits `[SetUp]` attribute for qUnit?

Answer (score 16):

### Registering a QUnit Callback

```
var mySetupFunc(details){/* setup code */}
QUnit.testStart(mySetupFunc);
```

---

### Callback Details

As of QUnit version 1.10.0pre-A, each registered [callback](http://api.qunitjs.com/category/callbacks/) will receive a hash as the first (and only) parameter. I've named mine 'details' in the example above. The contents of the hash vary by callback.  Here's a list of information in each hash.

**[begin](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.begin/)**
*(start of all tests)*

```
{}  /* empty hash */
```

**[done](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.done/)**
*(end of all tests)*

- failed: (int) total tests failed
- passed: (int) total tests passed
- total: (int) total tests run
- runtime: (int) how long tests took to run in milliseconds

**[log](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.log/)**
*(called within the ok() methods, etc)*

- result: (boolean) true if good, false if failed
- message: (string) whatever message you passed to ok()

**[testStart](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testStart/)**
*(called at the start of each test)*

- name: the name of the test (first argument passed to test() or asyncTest())
- module: the name of the module (if you haven't called the module() method, this will be undefined)

**[testDone](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testDone/)**
*(called at the end of each test)*

- name: (string) the name of the test (first argument passed to test() or asyncTest())
- module: (string) the name of the module (will be undefined if you never called module())
- failed: (int) count of assertions that failed
- passed: (int) count of assertions that succeeded
- total: (int) count of all assertions in the test

**[moduleStart](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.moduleStart/)**
*(called at the start of each module)*

- module: the name of the module

**[moduleDone](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.moduleDone/)**
*(called at the end of each test)*

- module: (string) the name of the module
- failed: (int) count of assertions that failed (total for all tests in module)
- passed: (int) count of assertions that succeeded (total for all tests in module)
- total: (int) count of all assertions in the module

---

### Examples

```
// There's probably a more elegant way of doing this, 
// but these two methods will add a row to a table for each test showing how long
// each test took.  
var profileStartTime = null;

function startTimer(details) {
  profileStartTime = new Date();
}

function stopTimer(details) {
  var stopDate = new Date();
  var duration = stopDate - profileStartTime;
  jQuery('#profiling').append(
    "<tr><td>" 
    + (details.module ? details.module + ":" : "") 
    + details.name 
    + "<\/td><td class='duration'>" 
    + duration 
    + "<\/td><\/tr>");
}

QUnit.testStart(startTimer);
QUnit.testDone(stopTimer);
```

My html table that is reference above looks like this:

```
<div style='margin: 10px 0;'>
  <table summary='profiling' class='profiling_table'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='profiling'>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> `QUnit.testStart(name)` is called whenever a new test batch of assertions starts running. `name` is the string name of the test batch.

See [the documentation](https://api.qunitjs.com/callbacks/) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I saw this but it isn't obvious as to how it should be used or what it should be used for. Now I know, thanks!

Comment: In case you don't know how to use this `QUnit.testStart = function (name) {};`

Comment: The term "test batch" is somewhat ambiguous. Is it the same as name in a test function definition: `test( name, [expected], test )`?

Comment: The method desribed by Juri is now deprecated.  The new methods is QUnit.testStart(function).  Pass the function as an argument rather than assigning testStart to it.  The current (1.10.0pre-A) allows for mutiple functions to be registered to a callback (testStart,testDone, etc).  The old way only allowed for one.

Answer (score 4):

Perry Tew's answer helped me greatly in solving this issue for myself, and if anyone is interested I wrote an encapsulated events object that will setup all the events for you to just hook into. See below:

**Please note that `console.log()` doesn't work on all browsers!**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="lib/qunit-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>

<!-- QUnit Events -->
<script>

    var testSetup = {

        begin       : function (data) /* before any tests start */ {
            console.log("begin: [" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + "]");
        },
        moduleStart : function (data) /* before the start of each module */ {
            console.log("-------\n  moduleStart:", data.name);
        },
        testStart   : function (data) /* before the start of each test */ {
            console.log("    testStart:", data.name);
        },
        log         : function (data) /* called after every assertion */ {
            console.log("      log:", data.message);
        },
        testDone    : function (data) /* after each test */ {
            console.log("    testDone:", data);
        },
        moduleDone  : function (data) /* after each module */ {
            console.log("  moduleDone:", data);
        },
        done        : function (data) /* all tests done */ {
            console.log("done:", data);
        },

        init : function () {
            QUnit.begin = testSetup.begin;
            QUnit.moduleStart = testSetup.moduleStart;
            QUnit.testStart = testSetup.testStart;
            QUnit.log = testSetup.log;
            QUnit.testDone = testSetup.testDone;
            QUnit.moduleDone = testSetup.moduleDone;
            QUnit.done = testSetup.done;
            console.log("\n======== QUnit events initialized ==========");
        }
    };

$(document).ready(testSetup.init);
</script>
```

Comment: very nice.  I will be using this.