# qUnit Teardown method

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

Is it possible to have teardown methods that run after every test in [qUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)? If not, are there any plugins around that will do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass it in the [module function](http://api.qunitjs.com/module/) like this:

```
module( "name", {teardown: function() {...}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to register a function with [QUnit.testDone(func)](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testDone/).
I have an example here:
[How do I run a function before each test when using qUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683416/how-do-i-run-a-function-before-each-test-when-using-qunit)