# Pass a parameter to qunit teardown?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'd like to call a particular method on an object that I create as part of `teardown`. This object is usually created for every test in the module. In the example code below, `cb.close()` must be called before `TC.destroy` is called. I checked and there are no arguments passed to teardown. Looking for a suggested approach that knows to close that tests `cb` control before tearing it down.

```
module('codebooks events', {
    setup: function () {
        if (typeof TC.init !== 'undefined') {
            TC.init({
                effects: false
            });
        }
    }, teardown: function () {
        if (TC.destroy) TC.destroy();
    }
});

test('search complete', function () {
    expect(1);
    var cb = TC.createControl({
        type: 'cb',
        el: $('#control-target')
    });
    stop();
    cb.on('cb:searchComplete', function () {
        ok(true, 'search completed');
        cb.close();
        start();
    });
    cb.tcTrigger('cb:search', { term: 'abc', book: 'dictionary' });
});

test('status updated', function () {
    expect(1);
    var cb = TC.createControl({
        type: 'cb',
        el: $('#control-target')
    });
    stop();
    cb.on('cb:statusUpdate', function () {
        ok(true, 'status updated');
        cb.close();
        start();
    });
    cb.tcTrigger('cb:search', { term: 'abc', book: 'dictionary' });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `cb` variable `global`. Then call `close()` on it inside your `teardown` callback.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683416/how-do-i-run-a-function-before-each-test-when-using-qunit) should contain all the QUnit callbacks that you need.

Comment: I thought about this but I have async tests so they will run in parallel won't they? I'd like to re-use the `cb` global and don't want to close the incorrect one.

Comment: @ryan Good point. I included a link that would probably be useful for you.